# How to do action upon a click of an A href

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to include a function upon a click of a button. The code basically retrieves rows of data from database and each row has an X button. I hope my explanation is clear!

```
 ( "</td><td><a href ='delete.php?id=".
        $row['trade_id']."'>X</a>
       </td></tr>"; )
```

. How do I do an action( include function) upon click of the ahref X ? How do i do this? example:

```
if (buttonclicked)
{
require 'function.php';
}
```

Php

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
 echo "<tr><td>" . $row['trade_id'] .         
        "</td><td>" . $row['selection'] . 
        "</td><td>" . $row['date'] .
        "</td><td>" . $row['type'] .
        "</td><td>" . $row['size'] .
        "</td><td>" . $row['bidprice'] .
        "</td><td>" . $row['offerprice'] .
        "</td><td>" . $row['stoploss'] .
        "</td><td>" . $row['takeprofit'] .
        "</td><td>" . $closedb . 
        "</td><td>" . $profit . 
        "</td><td><a href ='delete.php?id=".
        $row['trade_id']."'>X</a>
       </td></tr>";  

echo "</table><br>";
```

Comment: use $_GET['id'] and don't forget to sanitize inputs (google sql injection)

Answer (score 0):

delete.php

```
if(isset($_GET["id"])){
    require 'function.php';
}
```

Comment: but if its that way it will insert the last line of code into my databasee which i dont want.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])) { //Equals your "button clicked."
   $id = intval($_GET['id']); //Thats the ID you provided through "?id=1234".
   require 'function.php';
}
```

Comment: but if its that way it will insert the last line of code into my databasee which i dont want.

Answer (score 0):

in you delete.php file :

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] != null && $_GET['id'] != ""){
    require_once 'function.php';

    $myFunction = new myFunctionClass();
    $myFunction->DoMyDeleteLogic($_GET['id']); // protect data from get before

    //or static class
    MyFunctionClass::DoMyDeleteLogic($_GET['id']);
}
else{
    echo('datas missing...'); //put a throw exception
}
```

Comment: but if its that way it will insert the last line of code into my databasee which i dont want. i want to make the function work after the echo so that the file will insert the particular row of data.